# Google Analytics with Phonegap plugin for blackberry os6 and os7?

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics, blackberry-os6

I am making an app and I want to get analytics from the users. I got this code from google developer [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking?csw=1) i am able to build it correctlyand page load i am getting alert("called"). But I'm still seeing no hits in Google Analytics website itself. Can anyone help in figuring out the problem?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-52594810-1']);
   // _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);

   (function () {
       alert("called");
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Comment: IS there anyone who can help me?